# Simple Maths Riddle 1

Tags: riddle, mathematics

Here's an easy maths riddle I've come up with:

> I am prime to all aspects of mathematics, yet I am not prime myself.
>
> I have never lost a competition, nor drawn.
>
> My four-sided origins are not real, yet I occur naturally.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 1

I am prime to all aspects of mathematics, yet I am not prime myself.

> 1 is not prime, yet it is fundamental in maths

I have never lost a competition, nor drawn.

> Of course it hasn't, it has only 'won'

My four-sided origins are not real, yet I occur naturally.

> I'm assuming this is a reference to the imaginary number $i$, which is $\sqrt-1$

And then of course

> This is the Simple Maths Riddle number **1**!

Comment: that is what i was thinking it was, but wasnt sure how the last part fit in

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I'm the same as Dragonrage here, I've got the basics of the last line but don't fully understand it. Could you explain what the 4 sided origins are?

Comment: Regarding four sides: I guess that could be i^1 = i, i^2 = -1, i^3 = -i, i^4 = 1; on the complex plane they belong to the sides of the square with the center at 0,0.